# Find the solution to partial derivatives of $f(x, y; a, b, c)$ = $a$ $exp(2x)$ + $by^2$ + $cxy$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, partial-derivative

Below is a function $f$. We are interested in how changes in the values of the input variables $x,y$ or parameters $a,b,c$ affect $f$. To that aim, we write as a function of both its input variables and its parameters, using the notation $f(x, y; a, b, c)$. The “gradient of towards $v$”, denoted as $\nabla v$ $f$, is the vector of all partial derivatives of $f$ to the variables/parameters listed in $v$.

$f(x, y; a, b, c)$ = $a$ $exp(2x)$ + $by^2$ + $cxy$

what is the answer to following:

1. $\nabla x,y$  $f(x, y; a, b, c)$
2. $\nabla a,b,c$  $f(x, y; a, b, c)$
3. If $\delta$, $\epsilon$ are very small real numbers, what is $f(1,2; 3,4 + $$\delta$$, 5 + $$\epsilon$) $−$ $f(1,2; 3,4,5)$
   approximately? Explain how you obtained the answer.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Sorry Where is the PDE in your question ?

Comment: sorry, i mean partial derivatives